# Set 2D int array elements to 1 by memset function

Tags: c++, 2d, memset

In c++, we usually use `memset` to set all elements to zero like:

```
int a[5][5];
memset(a,0,sizeof(a));
```

What if I want set all int elements to **1**?

```
memset(a, 1, sizeof(a));
```

doesn't work since I cannot just set all bytes to **1**.

I wonder if there is similar function as `memset` to set all `elements`(**NOT JUST BYTES**) to a particular `value`.

Comment: Look at `std::fill` or `std::fill_n`

Comment: `In c++, we usually use memset to set all elements to zero` no, no we don't. We use much nicer things in C++. Are you thinking about C? You do know they're different languages, right?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I am a green hand in C++. I don't know more advanced things in C++. Could you suggest one to set all elements to 1?

Comment: @Zack I would suggest forgetting what C you know and learning C++ from a book. :) Afterwards, remember back what C you knew to start off with. Use either of them where appropriate. But **don't** write C++ code using the C mindset. (alternatives were suggested by chris).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `std::fill` will work, but you have to resort to using `reinterpret_cast<>`, which is often considered bad form:

```
#include <algorithm>

int a[5][5];
std::fill(reinterpret_cast<int*>(a),
          reinterpret_cast<int*>(a)+(5*5),
          1);
```

Alternatively, you could take the address of the first element, which is likewise clunky:

```
std::fill(&a[0][0],&a[0][0]+(5*5),1);
```

Comment: Or you could do it in a loop. I think doing it this way might be UB along the lines of out of bounds pointer arithmetic on the first dimension, even if it's in the whole array, but I'm not completely sure whether it is here.